# Typescript: how to stub function from imported namespace

Tags: typescript, namespaces, sinon, stub

I have the following files

```
// definition file
export namespace Foo {
  export function foo() {
    bar();
  }
  export function bar() {
    throw 'not implemented yet'
  }
}

// test file
import { Foo } from 'fooFile'
describe('', () => {
  it('', () => {
    const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    sandbox.stub(Foo, 'bar');
    Foo.foo(); // expected not to throw since I stubbed bar 
  });
});
```

and I don't know why it still throws. so far I've been able to stub functions imported from file with no namespace (`import * as Foo from`), methods and static methods from class, but I can't find the syntax for this stub.

Comment: What happens when you do `sandbox.stub(Foo.bar)`?

Comment: @KarolMajewski stub does not work and restore() does not remove the stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `bar` inside function `foo()` actually refers to local scope variable `bar`, but is undefined and then use global variable, which is defined. ([Reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/))

**AFAIK**, You can not create stub from variable inside function.

How to make sure that you call function bar() inside Foo namespace? Use `this.bar()` or `Foo.bar()`. Then now, your stub to method bar from namespace Foo can work in your test file (you have created stub correctly).

For example, file foo.ts

```js
export namespace Foo {
  export function foo() {
    this.bar(); // Or use: Foo.bar().
  }
  export function bar() {
    throw 'not implemented yet'
  }
}
```

test file: stackoverflow.test.ts

```js
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import { Foo } from './foo';

describe('', function () {
  it('', function () {
    const stubFooBar = sinon.stub(Foo, 'bar');

    Foo.foo();

    expect(stubFooBar.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    stubFooBar.restore();
  });
});
```

When I run it using mocha.

```
$ npx ts-mocha stackoverflow.test.ts --exit



    ✓ 


  1 passing (6ms)

$
```

Hope this helps.